# gocart session expiration, i want to show alert message

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-url

In the gocart while session is expired i want to show the alert message that session is expired . I know that session time will be config file but how to show a alert message while session is expired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best way to check session expired is to check the value that was store in the sessions exist or not.. if not session expired... and instead of alert you can use `flashmsg` in codeigniter to show the error and redirect it to other page..

example.

```
 if(!$this->session->userdata('youritem'){
     flashMsg('error','not in session (session expired');
 redirect(to/wher/you /want); 
 })
```